# Enable Tracing of Hosted WCF Service on Server

Tags: wcf

I have hosted a WCF application on server.
I need to trace the info,warnings and errors generated at server.
Please let me know the necessary changes need to be done.Please also let me know how to use the trace generated.

Regards,
Sachin K

Answer (score 7):

Maybe the official doc would help: [Configuring Tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx)

There is also a very interesting recent post from a WCF guy explaining the whole picture in detail here: [WCF Extensibility – System.Diagnostic Tracing](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/08/02/wcf-extensibility-system-diagnostic-tracing.aspx)

Comment: I have generated the trace log file.How to use it further.

Comment: Use the [Service Trace Viewer Tool (SvcTraceViewer.exe)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732023.aspx) to view and analyze the traces.